# Change zathuras display mode to single page only

Tags: pdf, display-settings, zathura

I recently switched from Debian to Arch. Now I have a newer version of zathura, which displays the pages continuously. For poppler as well as mupdf, I need the discrete display mode. Is this fixed now? I can't find an option to change this behaviour.

Comment: The current accepted solution is not good enough for me. So if someone knows how to not display the pages continuously, I am interested. This is interesting in particular with the full-screen mode for a presentation. I don't want part of the next slide to be shown if my screen has the bad ratio.

Comment: How about <kbd>f5</kbd> which will start the presentation mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "best-fit" mode and use Pageup + Pagedown (or map k,j) to jump to the previous or next page.

Does that help?

Comment: Well it worked. Although I thought it did not yesterday. Hmmm... anyway thank you

Comment: I just want to add that this answer does not work when viewing a "landscape" pdf (i.e. a pdf file with pages that are wider than they are tall) in a "portrait" window (i.e. a window that is taller than it is wide). In this situation, "best-fit" will still show "page bleed" i.e. you will see the preceding/following pages above/below the page that you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround. If you set the page padding to a large number, you will not see the previous and following pages; for example:

```
:set page-padding 300
```

Navigate with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

The position of the document within the window is not centered, though :-(

Answer (score 1):

As [@pranphy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/162584/pranphy) mentioned in the comments, you can go to the presentation mode by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. Worked for me pretty well. By the way, to use `jk` navigation in this mode you need now to press `Shift + [j,k]`.